# how to set duration, fading start time and end time video wise in below command?

Tags: ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -y -i intro.mp4 -i video.mp4  -i outro.mp4 -f lavfi -i color=black:s=1280x720 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=out:st=10:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; \
 [1:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=10:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+10/TB[v1]; \
 [2:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=10:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+20/TB[v2]; \
 [3:v]trim=duration=30[over]; \
 [over][v0]overlay[over1]; \
 [over1][v1]overlay[over2]; \
 [over2][v2]overlay=format=yuv420[outv]" \
-vcodec libx264 -map '[outv]' merge.mp4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fade out timings are one second too late - the fade out should start at 9 seconds of each clip so that it can end by 10 seconds.

```
ffmpeg -y -i intro.mp4 -i video.mp4  -i outro.mp4 -f lavfi -i color=black:s=1280x720:d=30 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=out:st=9:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; \
 [1:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=9:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+10/TB[v1]; \
 [2:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=9:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+20/TB[v2]; \
 [3][v0]overlay[over1]; \
 [over1][v1]overlay[over2]; \
 [over2][v2]overlay=format=yuv420[outv]" \
-vcodec libx264 -map '[outv]' merge.mp4
```

---

If you have audio as well in the 3 files, use

```
ffmpeg -y -i intro.mp4 -i video.mp4  -i outro.mp4 -f lavfi -i color=black:s=1280x720:d=30 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=out:st=9:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; \
 [1:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=9:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+10/TB[v1]; \
 [2:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=9:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+20/TB[v2]; \
 [3][v0]overlay[over1]; \
 [over1][v1]overlay[over2]; \
 [over2][v2]overlay=format=yuv420[outv]; \
 [0][1][2]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[outa]" \
-vcodec libx264 -map '[outv]' -map '[outa]' merge.mp4
```

This command assumes that all 3 files have 10 seconds of audio each, eolse sync will be lost.

Comment: this command works but voice is disabled. so how to enable audio?

Comment: How to know video file has audio? we will have with audio and without audio so which command do you think is best for this purpose?

Comment: Run `ffprobe -v 0 -select_streams a -show_entries stream=index -of compact=p=0:nk=1 "$file" | wc -l` . If it's zero, no audio in $file